# What function does the "//" operator provide in Lua?

Tags: lua, operators

I've been seeing the `//` operator a whole bunch as I work with Lua on the TIC-80. However, I've been unable to find any documentation on it. The use cases for this that I've generally seen are something like this:

```
n = t%60//30*2
```

the input/output table for this function is as follows:

```
 t|n
0 |0
15|0
30|2
45|2
60|0
75|0
etc...
```

This is often used for switching between sprites at set rates, and I understand what comes out of it, I just don't understand how.

Comment: [floor division](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1). Rounds the quotient towards minus infinity.

Comment: Thanks, @siffiejoe ! I was pretty confused. I guess just searching // doesn't give you much when every URL has that string in it

Comment: instead of searching the web you could simply search the Lua manual... what do you think people write it for?

Comment: Precedence: `n = ((t%60)//30)*2`

Answer (score 15):

From the Lua reference manual, [3.4.1 Arrithmetic Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.1):

> Lua supports the following arithmetic operators:
>
> ```
> +: addition
> -: subtraction
> *: multiplication
> /: float division
> //: floor division
> %: modulo
> ^: exponentiation
> -: unary minus
> ```
>
> Floor division (//) is a division that rounds the quotient towards
>   minus infinity, that is, the floor of the division of its operands.

The floor division operator was introduced in Lua 5.3

Please refer to manuals.